# emacs elisp switch to buffer and follow

Tags: shell, emacs, buffer

I am trying to write a command that will cause Emacs to switch to a new buffer and do something (in this case, execute a shell command) that writes output to the buffer.

```
(defun test-func ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((bname "*temp*")
        (default-directory "/home/me"))
    (with-output-to-temp-buffer bname
      (switch-to-buffer bname)
      (shell-command "ls -l" bname))))
```

In this case, it "works" except that it doesn't switch the buffer until after the command is done executing. I wanted to switch immediately and then follow the output as it's running. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `redisplay` explicitly after `switch-to-buffer` to make it visible.

Note that `ls` is a fairly "fast" command, and it is unlikely to show piecemeal. You might want to try a shell script like

```
while true; do
  date
  sleep 10
done
```

and run is asynchronously (either use `async-shell-command` or add `&` to the end of the command line).

Note also that the help for `shell-command` says:

> In Elisp, you will often be better served by calling `call-process` or
>   `start-process` directly, since it offers more control and does not impose the use of a shell (with its need to quote arguments).

Comment: Yea, that switches to the buffer but the buffer doesn't update until the shell command finishes... Maybe there's a different way to call out.

Comment: looks like redisplay and then start-process can be made to do it.